# I am unable to do a push-up, how can I improve?

Tags: training, push-ups, warm-up

I'm unable to do push ups. I have problems balancing my weight during the exercise. What am I doing wrong?
Do I have to do specific warm-ups or is there anything else I can do to improve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to warm up before doing a modest number of push ups?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/is-it-necessary-to-warm-up-before-doing-a-modest-number-of-push-ups)

Comment: While it sounds like a duplicate I think the real question is "I can't do a single push up, what can I do?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i got your question right, you can't do a single push-up and you want to change that.
There are several ways to make "easier" push-ups. You can try to:

- do them on your knees
- standing/leaning against a wall
- with your hands in a higher position, on a chair or sth.

If you just want to be able to do push-ups, i think you can start by doing some of these exercises until you are ready.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is about how to keep your balance while doing one, spread your legs a little further apart. Hands should be shoulder width, and legs can be about the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't yet do a full push-up, I'd work on your planks (from your elbows and also from a full push-up position), trying to keep your entire trunk, abs, and butt squeezed for several sets of 30 seconds to a minute. I'd also do incline push-ups using a wall or chair, and try some Down Dog from yoga.