# How to have short work outs per day to compensate 1 day gym

Tags: workout-routines, workout, strength-training

I have started to do workouts just recently, and I am doing weight training, but I seem to have a very busy schedule so I only get to go to the gym **once a week**.

What I do currently though is **I jog around 1.5k before going to work everyday**(from the parking lot to the office, around 5 blocks away), but I feel it's not enough.

**I do have some dumbbells at home** but I don't know which exercises should I use so I could compensate for the lack of time in the gym.

I can usually have half an hour to an hour of free time when I come home from work, so I am looking for exercises that I could do before going to bed. I want to do it at night since I get home at around 8pm, and because I have to be up early morning to go to work(I leave the house at around 5:30 am).

What exercises would be the most effective based on my schedule (gym once a week, jog every day) and resources(dumbbells at home, half an hour per day)?

Comment: What type of job do you have where you have to work from 5:30 am to 8pm?

Comment: People who try to work out at home typically do not have the space or extra equipment (eg. benches or the equivalent) to get a worthwhile workout. Do you have both?  If not, you may want to look at using rubber bands.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help you, see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/13078/3778

Comment: @Chad I'm a Web developer and my division is a little bit understaffed at the moment so I work an hour or 2 later than my work hours.

Comment: @rrirower I only have dumbbells and a treadmill. I don't actually have the space to accomodate benches in my room.

Comment: What are your training goals?

Comment: @Kate My goals are: remove the belly fat, increase the size and tone my arms. build a better chest and remove the fats on my neck. I'm actually doing it because I'm thinking of shifting my career to be a flight steward, and I was advised  by a flight steward and a flight steward trainer that to pass I must be a little bit more fit.(I have a small frame but I have gotten fat from fast-food). I need to have lost the belly fat and at least increased my arm size by half an inch by the end of january. Is that possible? Are there diets that I could use to speed up my weight training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current training schedule, your basic load of low intensity training is in the recommended range of 2-3 hours (120 to 180 minutes, see e.g. [CDC recommendation](http://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/everyone/guidelines/adults.html)) per week.

Assuming that the 1.5k run takes 8-10 minutes and you do this twice a day, five days a week plus 60 minutes in the gym -> 140 to 160 minutes.

The basic load of high intensity does not have to be that high, [NY times: The 4-minute workout](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/06/19/the-4-minute-workout/?_r=0), e.g. one 4 minute high intensity exercise per week.

So the recommendation is (given that you don't have a specific goal and don't want to over train):

- Once or twice a week do a 4 minute [tabata](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=tabata), e.g. with
  [burpees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYfNA_lmkHM) or [mountain climbers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyeZM-_VnRc).
- For those days you skip the parking log jog, take a walk or slow jog
  at night

Assuming that the dumbbells are too light to impact your large muscule groups and given your available limited time, they are of little use. Consider replacing them with one or two [kettlebells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettlebell)

Comment: I'll try this one for a couple of weeks and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I miss the gym, i do around 200 squats and 100 crunches and perhaps Jogging for 15-20 mins. If you have dumbbells, then you can do some upper body exercises as well like overhead, side-bending etc.

Comment: 200 squats! I'm assuming you mean without weight? Isn't that a lot of stress on the knees?

Comment: Yes of course without any weights... Well it all depends. I started with 10 squats per day when i started to work out like 2 yrs ago. Also i do squats in a set of 50. So its like 4 sets of squats and same with the crunches.